# How do I differentiate my local dev database from my live production database when executing mysql script in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, localserver

I am the sole dev working with a very large warehouse management system for a small business.  Our software is housed on a local server that is only accessible within the building, but I also have a local copy of the system on my machine to use for development purposes before things get pushed to a git repository to be pulled into the live system.  Pretty standard stuff.

The database is huge, as it contains data for every order and every product and every customer the company has obtained or produced since the beginning of the company, around 10 years ago.  I obviously have to keep my local database up-to-date for troubleshooting specific orders, etc. and I can't just import a database with millions of records using phpmyadmin, so I use [BigDump](https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) to stagger the import whenever I need to update my local dev db to match the production db.

**Here is my problem:** Before I can import the updated DB with BigDump, I have to completely drop the dev db and create a blank one with the same name.  So I run the script:

```
DROP DATABASE db_name;
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

I **KNOW** this is very dangerous and am terrified that one day I will accidentally run this on the production db and completely delete our entire warehouse db. (We of course backup the production db regularly, but we get orders every minute or more and if I accidentally drop the db, there is a good chance we will lose a lot of data).

**What should I add to the script to make sure it only runs if it is my local machine's development db server?**  I know that I can add a use statement for the db_name or just make the db_name different on my dev server, but it is a legacy piece of software that I didn't design and for various reasons, I have to keep the db_name the same in both environments.  Is there a way to set a use statement for the server_name?  Both servers are named localhost, so does that throw another wrench in the situation?  As you may be able to tell, server configuration is not my strongest skillset.

Here are my two DB server specs (if that is helpful):

> **Local Dev DB Serber**
>   
>   Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
>   Server type: MySQL
>   Server version: 5.7.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   Protocol version: 10
>   Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
>   
>   **Live Production DB Server**
>   
>   Server: MariaDB 10 (Localhost via UNIX socket)
>   Server type: MariaDB
>   Server version: 10.0.32-MariaDB - Source distribution
>   Protocol version: 10
>   Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Write a script that will do it for you. Take the weakest link out of the equation, which is you.

Comment: Can you not simply adjust your permissions on prod so drop table never works with the account your code uses?

Comment: Don't `DROP` first.  Create the new copy, then `RENAME`.  (Alas, you must rename each table, not the whole database.)  Rename the real tables out of the way, then the new ones into place.  Then pause to make sure you are looking at the right system before doing `DROP`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of a dba question than a PHP question IMHO. But this is relevant. I would prevent the drop_priv on any remote users of the production database.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET drop_priv = 'N' WHERE user='...' AND host='...' and db='...';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I would look at this link for more details.

[Prevent Drop Databases From MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27372/blocking-drop-database-command)

And what I would actually do is make sure there are 2 different user accounts for each database. On the production database, only ever EVER access it from your 'dev-name'@'my-pc-name-or-ip' account if you need to access it locally. And make sure that user cannot drop databases. Strict adherence to utilizing 'user-name'@'ip-address' for permissions, instead of doing 'username'@'%' will go a long way here.

Do not ever use the full root permission user on the production database. There's no need. There's also no need for any external user to have drop permissions on your production database, really. If it were me, and I was running the risk of dropping all tables in production in some corner of a work flow, I would make sure the only user that has drop privileges is 'root'@'localhost'

Also, I would check your backup policy in the event of worst case. You should know how often its backing up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use environment variables. Here is a nice article:
[Using Environment Variables in PHP](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643130/using-environment-variables-in-php)

You should define your env., like `ENV=dev` or `ENV=prod` etc. in the configuration of your Apache or Nginx host. Here is an example for Apache conf of v-host:
[enter link description here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)

Then just check your environment in the code. Here is an example
[enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.getenv.php)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).